# Need to make shorter text (Having problems with text-overflow: ellipsis)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with the property text-overflow: ellipsis. As I've been reading you can't use it with display table-cell but I have tons of table-cells with teams names and some of them are really big and in somes resolutions it doesn't fit (see pictures below).

If the name is big but with several small words there is no problem, the problem is when there is one big word (approx 15 letters). I would need to make shorter that word with "..." or something to evoid what is happening on the pictures.

Any suggestion or tip how to do it with CSS, Jquery or javascript?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Also the number next to the name should fit.

HTML:

```
<div class="betHandle team2">
 <i class="logo"></i>
 <span class="name">
    <i>
     <em>4.50</em>
    </i>

    <b>FC CHAYKA PESCHANOKOPSKOYE</b>
 </span>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.name{
 line-height: 3.28em;
 display: table;
}

b{
 font-weight: 300;
 display: table-cell;
 line-height: 1em;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-right: 1em;
 width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Ok]

[image: Not Ok]

Comment: use CSS property white-space:nowrap. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use a `div` instead `b` and set div

```
    <div class="betHandle team2">
       <i class="logo"></i>
        <div class="name">
           <div class="divId">4.50</div> <div class="divId">FC CHAYKA PESCHANOKOPSKOYE</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

and style:

```
.name{
   font-weight: 300;
   overflow: hidden;

}
.name div{
   display:inline-block;
}

.divId{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check scrollon class in css. increase the size of that particular by using a class

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
width: 200px; /* choose the width you want */
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Here is an example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXdLwO

Answer (score 0):

```
.name{
 line-height: 3.28em;
 display: table;
}

b{
 font-weight: 300;
 display: table-cell;
 line-height: 1em;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 padding-right: 1em;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ - thank you for your suggestion. I will keep in mind. :-)